# How to make the repeated js code into one?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

In order to display math equation, I insert the following code into my html webpage, but I think there are many repeated code.

I hope to place the all code into a file, and alll html quote  the file, how can I do? Thanks!

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    },
    "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

**BTW:**

I try to write the following code into aa.js

aa.js

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js", "asciimath2jax.js", "toMathML.js"],
    "HTML-CSS": { imageFont: null },
    showMathMenu: false,
    showMathMenuMSIE: false,
    TeX: { extensions: ["AMSmath.js", "AMSsymbols.js", "noUndefined.js"] },
    jax: ["input/TeX", "input/AsciiMath", "output/HTML-CSS"]
});
```

and insert the following code into my html webpage, but the webpage occur error.

```
   <script src="Js/aa.js" type="text/x-mathjax-config"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="Math/MathJax.js"></script>
```

and if I insert the following code into my html webpage, aa.js don't affect.

```
<script src="Js/aa.js" type="text/x-mathjax-config"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any repeated code there. Which part is repeated?

Comment: All html  web page  about math need insert the code above, it's repeated.

Comment: Just save it to another file and include it in every page: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm Using in-line configuration option, how can I save it to a new file and include in evry page? could you give me some sample code?

Comment: As `aa.js` calls a function in `MathJax.js`, you need to put it after `MathJax.js` in your html

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.